# Same controller loads twice before segue (programatically) to second VC in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have come across similar issues but nothing like my current setup and thus struggling to find a fix.

I have a custom `UIViewController` extension with two functions which programmatically presents and dismisses a VC (see below).

```
extension UIViewController {

    //present VC fromRight
    func presentDetail(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController){
        //constant to hold animation
        let transition = CATransition()

        transition.duration =  0.3 //seconds
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
        self.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

        present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }//end func

    //dismiss VC fromLeft
    func dismissDetail(){
        //constant to hold animation
        let transition = CATransition()

        transition.duration =  0.3 //seconds
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
        self.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }//end func
}
```

I have a `VenueListVC` (primary VC) that has a `UITableView`, my `didSelectRowAt` function is below which presents (using the custom extension above) a `VenueDetailsVC` (secondary VC).

**My issue is that when a cell is selected the primary VC (VenueListVC) is loaded twice before modally presenting the secondary VC (VenueDetailsVC). I have no other segues between these two VCs.**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let venueDetailsVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VenueDetailsVC") as? VenueDetailsVC else { return }  //create an instance of VenueDetailsVC

    presentDetail(venueDetailsVC)//present Group Feed VC using custom extension
}
```

Comment: This happen because you have add "kCATransitionPush". so it shows push transition and then present the view.

Comment: thanks @Khushbu but I've tried all other transition types other than "kCATransitionPush" and it does not work. The behaviour I am currently getting is that the primary VC slides across from the right twice before the secondary VC suddenly appears.

Comment: I think view is not loading twice. Add breakpoints in "cellForRowAt" method in tableview and check it.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean add a breakpoints?

Comment: I mean your view is not loading twice. You can check it by debugging. So, add breakpoints for that.

Comment: You mean “cellForRowAt” or “didSelectRowAt”? What specifically am I looking for with?

Comment: @RIG - you said *"I have no other segues between these two VCs"* ... when you say "no other" does that mean you have ***A*** Segue defined?

Comment: How you are judging that - "primary VC (VenueListVC) is loaded twice before modally presenting the secondary VC" ?

Comment: @DonMag I mean I haven’t set segues in my storyboard. I segue (transition) using presentDtail() and dismiss() in my ViewCrontroller extension.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal when I tap in a cell in my primary controller, the same primary controller slides from the right until the secondary controller suddenly pops up. So it appears that the primary controller is loading again when I tap in a cell.

Comment: @RIG - it seems something else must be going on in code you haven't shown. Quick test, no problems: https://github.com/DonMag/CustomPresent

Comment: @DonMag thanks for the test, I've had a look and yes I have a similar setup so it is very strange that my code is behaving a little different. It appears that the secondary VC being presented is very slow at coming to view for some reason.

Comment: @DonMag using your project I was able t replicate the issue that I am having with mine, if you tap between selecting a cell and dismissing the presented view a few times quickly, you will notice that the second 'VenueDetailsVC' starts to lag and thus causing the first VC to look like is loaded twice.

Comment: @Roggie - yep, I can see that happening. Add this as the first line in `didSelectRow` --- `tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)` --- it *seems* like UIKit is maybe *buffering* the current view... That appears to correct the issue for me.

Comment: @DonMag that didn't work, but adding this did 'DispatchQueue.main.async { self.presentDetail(venueDetailsVC)}'